# Filter scene overlap in image collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, google-earth-engine-python-api

How can I filter areas of scene overlap so that each pixel only has data from one landsat scene? My goal is to have as many images as possible while also maintaining a uniform number of images across the area of interest.

Here is a map showing image count in the collection (darker areas have more images):
[image]

I have made attempts to filter to only 1 lansdat scene per pixel but can only get something like the following:
[image]

Here is the code I have been using:

```py
def get_landsat_collection(landsat_num, start_date, end_date, aoi, min_qual, max_cc):
    if landsat_num == 4:
        ls_col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_SR').select(
            ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'pixel_qa'],
            ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2', 'pixel_qa']
        ).filterMetadata(
            'IMAGE_QUALITY', 'not_less_than', min_qual
        ).filterMetadata(
            'CLOUD_COVER', 'not_greater_than', max_cc
        )
    elif landsat_num == 5:
        ls_col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR').select(
            ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'pixel_qa'],
            ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2', 'pixel_qa']
        ).filterMetadata(
            'IMAGE_QUALITY', 'not_less_than', min_qual
        ).filterMetadata(
            'CLOUD_COVER', 'not_greater_than', max_cc
        )
    elif landsat_num == 7:
        ls_col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR').select(
            ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'pixel_qa'],
            ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2', 'pixel_qa']
        ).filterMetadata(
            'IMAGE_QUALITY', 'not_less_than', min_qual
        ).filterMetadata(
            'CLOUD_COVER', 'not_greater_than', max_cc
        )
    elif landsat_num == 8:
        ls_col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR').select(
            ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'pixel_qa'],
            ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2', 'pixel_qa']
        ).filterMetadata(
            'IMAGE_QUALITY_OLI', 'not_less_than', min_qual
        ).filterMetadata(
            'CLOUD_COVER', 'not_greater_than', max_cc
        )
    else:
        raise ValueError("Landsat 4, 5, 7, 8 are acceptable options")

    ls_col = ls_col.filterBounds(aoi).filterDate(start_date, end_date)
    return ls_col

def mask_clouds(image):
    qa = image.select('pixel_qa')
    shadow_bit_mask = 1 << 3
    cloud_bit_mask = 1 << 5
    cloud_mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloud_bit_mask).eq(0).And(
        qa.bitwiseAnd(shadow_bit_mask).eq(0))
    masked_img = image.updateMask(cloud_mask).copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
    return masked_img

def mask_water(image):
    qa = image.select('pixel_qa')
    water_bit_mask = 1 << 2
    water_mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(water_bit_mask).eq(0)
    masked_img = image.updateMask(water_mask).copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
    return masked_img

def mask_snow(image):
    qa = image.select('pixel_qa')
    snow_mask = 1 << 4
    mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(snow_mask).eq(0)
    masked_img = image.updateMask(mask).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])
    return masked_img

start_yr = 1985
end_yr = 2021

image_qual_min = 9
cloud_cc_max = 50
nys_coords = [
    [-79.99688779, 40.40498417],
    [-71.65014432, 40.40498417],
    [-71.65014432, 44.97328983],
    [-79.99688779, 44.97328983]
]

aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(nys_coords)
aoi_ls_collections = []

for year in range(start_yr, end_yr):
    ls_4_col = utils.get_landsat_collection(4, str(year) + '-01-01', str(year) + '-12-31', aoi, image_qual_min,
                                            cloud_cc_max)
    ls_5_col = utils.get_landsat_collection(5, str(year) + '-01-01', str(year) + '-12-31', aoi, image_qual_min,
                                            cloud_cc_max)
    ls_8_col = utils.get_landsat_collection(8, str(year) + '-01-01', str(year) + '-12-31', aoi, image_qual_min,
                                            cloud_cc_max)
    ls_7_col = utils.get_landsat_collection(7, str(year) + '-01-01', str(year) + '-12-31', aoi, image_qual_min,
                                                cloud_cc_max)
    ls_col = ls_4_col.merge(ls_5_col.merge(ls_7_col.merge(ls_8_col)).sort('system:time_start')
    ls_col = ls_col.map(utils.add_ndvi)
    ls_col = ls_col.map(utils.mask_clouds)
    ls_col = ls_col.map(utils.mask_snow)
    ls_col = ls_col.map(utils.mask_water)
    ls_col = ls_col.map(lambda img: img.clip(aoi))
    aoi_ls_collections.append(ls_col)

aoi_ls_collection = aoi_ls_collections.pop(0)
for col in aoi_ls_collections:
    aoi_ls_collection = aoi_ls_collection.merge(col)

input_rp_image = aoi_ls_collection.map(lambda x: ee.Image(ee.Number(x.get("WRS_PATH")).add(ee.Number(x.get("WRS_ROW")).multiply(1000))).toInt16().updateMask(x.select('NDVI').mask()))
input_rp_stack = input_rp_image.toArray().arrayProject([0])
rp_mask = input_rp_stack.arraySort(input_rp_stack).arraySlice(0, -1,).arrayFlatten([["mask"]])
test_collection_masked = aoi_ls_collection.map(lambda x: x.updateMask(ee.Image(ee.Number(x.get("WRS_PATH")).add(ee.Number(x.get("WRS_ROW")).multiply(1000))).toFloat().eq(rp_mask)))

args = dict(
    folder="GEE_DUMP",
    scale=30,
    crs='EPSG:26918',
    region=aoi,
    maxPixels=500000000
)

nys_count_task = geetools.batch.Export.image.toDrive(
    image=test_collection_masked.select('NDVI').count(),
    description="ccdc_filtered_input_count_nys_12142020",
    **args
)

nys_count_task.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_api_05
read this, should be helping.

Use different reducers to composite images.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that link takes me to a 404 page

Comment: Kindly, check the URL before sharing :)

Comment: Ok, the link works now. But it doesn't quite solve my problem. The examples there show how to reduce the image collection to one image through mosaicking and compositing. I need each pixel to hold a time series (> 1 observations), and actually the more observations per pixel the better, but I need these observations to be relatively uniform across the area of interest. So for my needs compositing is too aggressive.